# Unable to connect a windows system as slave using JNLP

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jnlp, jenkins-agent

I have the Jenkins master running on SUSE linux. I want to connect a Windows 8.1 system as a slave using JNLP. I followed the [Jenkins CLI Connection mechanism guide](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI#JenkinsCLI-Connectionmechanism) and changed the Jenkins global security configuration.

Under TCP-Port for JNLP-Slave, I selected Static and entered the port as 49187. When the launch the JNLP connection on Slave system, after a while I get the "Read Timeout" error.

Could someone suggest what I am doing wrong?

```
Error  
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) 
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) 
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionS10.run(Unknown Source) 
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionS10.run(Unknown Source) 
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStreamO(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source) 
  at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:206) Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketReadO(Native Method) 
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source) 
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) 
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) 
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source) 
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source) 
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source) 
  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source) 
  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source) 
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStreamO(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) 
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(Unknown Source) 
  at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:205)
```

Comment: Can you try to disable the firewall on your Windows slave?

Comment: Hi Bruno, Thanks for the reply. Firewall is already disabled. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to launch the slave with a Java command line from your Windows machine? (==> java -jar slave.jar ...)

Comment: Yes i tried launching the slave using command line too. C:\slave_jar>java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://serverHost:8080/c
omputer/Windows_Slave/slave-agent.jnlp , But i got error "Failing to obtain http://ServerHost:8080/computer/Windows_Slave/sl
ave-agent.jnlp
java.io.IOException: Failed to load http://ServerHost:8080/compute
r/Windows_Slave/slave-agent.jnlp: 503 Service Unavailable
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.parseJnlpArguments(Launcher.java:275)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:219)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:192)"

Comment: Your Jenkins user is admin on the Windows machine? With this user, are you able to ping the Linux master server?

Comment: Hi Bruno.  Thanks for your quick response. I don't have any user created on Jenkins. However with my admin user on Windows i am able to ping the linux master.

Comment: Using `curl` and `nc` tools verify that the instance can be accessed through the remoting channel. https://documentation.cloudbees.com/docs/cjoc-user-guide/_validating_installation.html